# ParametricNDSolveValue vs NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

My question is simple. If I define this system of differential equation with `NDSolveValue` I obtain a pretty result

```
{ysol, wsol} = NDSolveValue[{y[t] == 1/Sqrt[w[t]]*w'[t], 1/Sqrt[w[t]]*(y'[t] + 3 y[t]) == 0, 
y[-20] == 5, w[-20] == 3}, {y, w}, {t, -20, 10}]
```

but if I try to do the same with `ParametricNDSolveValue` (with the idea of setting `a==1`) it does not work.

```
{ypsol, wpsol} = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y[t] == a/Sqrt[w[t]]*w'[t],
1/Sqrt[w[t]]*(y'[t] + 3 y[t]) == 0, y[-20] == 5, w[-20] == 3}, {y, w}, {t, -20, 10}, {a}]
```

Why is it so? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParametricNDSolveValue` gives one result depending on the parameter.

Try

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y[t] == a/Sqrt[w[t]]*w'[t], 1/Sqrt[w[t]]*(y'[t] + 3 y[t]) == 0, y[-20] == 5, w[-20] == 3}, {y,w}, {t, -20, 10}, {a}]
```

`sol[1]`gives the list of solutions:

```
Plot[Through[sol[1][t]], {t, -20, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you. How do I access to the single functions `w[t]` and `y[t]`?

Comment: @Lele, it is simple: `y[a_, t_] := sol[a][[1]][t], w[a_, t_] := sol[a][[2]][t]`. And I would add `Evaluate` to `Plot[Evaluate@Through[sol[1][t]], {t, -20, 10}]` to clearly see curves with different colors.